# Can't start a service (sudo) remotely from script and keep it running

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a service (tomcat) that needs sudo to be started. I made a simple script on the remote server in /root/bin/test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo service tomcat start
read
```

(The script needs to do other stuff too, just pared down for simplicity). When I run a it directly on the remote server, tomcat starts and continues running on the server after I disconnect.

When I run it remotely, the process starts, (I can see it when paused for the "read"), but once the script ends, it's gone.
(while paused for the read, run this command locally)

`ps -ef | grep tomcat`

I've tried various combinations of nohup, screen, and & on the commands both on the local machine and in the remote machine's test.sh script, but I can't seem to get it working.

```
ssh -t gregb@111.111.111.111 "/root/bin/test.sh"
ssh -t gregb@111.111.111.111 "nohup /root/bin/test.sh"
ssh -t gregb@111.111.111.111 "nohup /root/bin/test.sh &"
ssh -t gregb@111.111.111.111 "screen /root/bin/test.sh &"
```

Comment: Have you already checked (in /var/log/syslog e.g.) if the service stops because errors are encountered?

Answer (score 0):

Start a screen session in the background and run your script in it. This works for me with top which is interactive "like sudo".

```
ssh -l jaroslav  10.3.0.7 screen -dmS foobar
ssh -l jaroslav  10.3.0.7 screen -S foobar -X stuff top^M

# ^M means [return]
#ssh -l jaroslav  10.3.0.7 screen -S foobar -X stuff top
#ssh -l jaroslav  10.3.0.7 screen -S foobar -X stuff $'\015'

# to resume
ssh -t -l jaroslav 10.3.0.7 screen -r -S foobar
```

To be honest, this is kind of a backwards way to start a service, but I'm not exactly sure why tomcat is terminated when you ssh into the box with ssh -t. After all, the service runs in the background, right?